# Bing maps is not responding to code. WPF applicaition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to add some pushpins to bing maps through the c# code, but nothing is happening. I have tried to add it through the XAML, it did work.but whem I'm adding the pushpin through the c# code it's not working.
Here's the XAML Code:

```
    <Window x:Class="Drone_Tracker.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Drone_Tracker"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>
        <m:Map x:Name="myMap" Mode="AerialWithLabels"
               CredentialsProvider="MYAPIKEY" Margin="5,5,5,5" 
               />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and here's the cs code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ViewAllData_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // MyMap.Children.Clear();
             Pushpin pin = new Pushpin
             {
                 Location = new Location(25.001305, 54.990186)
             }; 
            myMap.Children.Add(pin);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*it's not working*" is not a sufficient problem description. Please try to be more specific.

Comment: Where `ViewAllData_Clicked` handler is wired? Xaml is missing any button.

Comment: The XAML file doesn't seem to be responding to the cs file. I tried to make other things, nothing happened

Comment: it seems that I forgot wiring `ViewAllData_Clicked ` there,

Comment: What should be the best attribute to add this method for the xaml
I want to populate the pushpins automatically without clicking or making anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, I defined the pushpins in a function and did not bind it with the XAML code. I have solved it by putting the pushpins code in the MainWindow constructor.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Pushpin pin = new Pushpin
        {
            Location = new Location(25.001305, 54.990186)
        };
        myMap.Children.Add(pin);

    }
```